# Way to change height of UILabel in cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitableview

This is my first question so please do excuse me if I have broken guidelines.
I will post code down below and would appreciate any input. Easy technique is preferred.
So, to the question.
I have a custom cell and a label inside of it. I want the size of the label to change. I have already got a way for the table cell height to change but I haven't worked out how to change the size of the label.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("messageCell") as! MessageTableViewCell

    let receiveTextSize: CGFloat = cell.receivedMessage.intrinsicContentSize().width
    let sendTextSize: CGFloat = cell.sentMessage.intrinsicContentSize().width

    cell.receivedMessage.alpha = 0
    cell.sentMessage.alpha = 0

    if messageReceived[indexPath.row] {
        if receiveTextSize >= 220 {
            cell.sentMessage.frame.size = CGSizeMake(cell.sentMessage.frame.width, 100)

        }
        cell.receivedMessage.text = messageContent[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.receivedMessage.alpha = 1
    } else {
        if sendTextSize >= 220 {
            cell.sentMessage.frame.size = CGSizeMake(cell.sentMessage.frame.width, 100)
            cell.sentMessage.numberOfLines = 0
        }
        cell.sentMessage.text = messageContent[indexPath.row] as String
        cell.sentMessage.alpha = 1

    }

    cell.receivedMessage.sizeToFit()

    cell.receivedMessage.frame.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100)

    return cell
}
```

**Edit** Solution was to set auto-constraints and then change the heightForRowAtIndexPath function for the tableView

Comment: have you setup constraints between the label and the cell? how are you setting the cell height?

Comment: Thanks! Just before you commented I tried this! I can't believe it was that simple.